# Two Men - The Physicist and Plumber

Tags: word, situation

You have two men in a room. You know for a fact that one is a physicist and the other is a plumber. Sadly both men have recently been rendered totally deaf and haven't learned sign language. This is a problem because you have to tell which one is the physicist who can bring the run-away LHC under control and which is the plumber here to unclog the toilet.

You have a piece of paper and a pen. What single word do you write down and ask them to say to determine which is which?

<sub>Anyone that says plumber or physicist shall be squashed under an irrelevant elephant.</sub>

Comment: Um... Erm... Are you a plumber?

Comment: What single word, and they've got to say it

Comment: Whats LHC, pardon my ignorance

Comment: [Large Hadron Collider](http://www.hasthelhcdestroyedtheearth.com/)

Comment: "Plumber?" Just form their title as a question as if to say "Bob?" "Bob is that you?"

Comment: You shall be squashed under a gazelle, as per my question edit :P

Comment: @James Mean! Lol.

Comment: How exactly do you ask them to say the word?

Comment: You don't, that's how you tell. The physicist will say 'Un-ion-ized' and the plumber will say 'union-ized'

Comment: @JamesMassey, I think that what COTO means is: you have written "unionised" on a piece of paper. They read it silently without moving their lips. They glance at each other, confused. They look at you expecting clarification. Now what? It would have been much more useful to write "profession?"

Comment: @JamesMassey You mean under an irrelevant elephant, right?

Comment: @tobyink's was my concern as well. How do you know they will say the word you write? A strange person holds a card up with a word on it, my first inclination isn't to read it out.

Comment: This comes from Isaac Asimov's [To Tell a Chemist](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1865127)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> "Unionized". The idea is that the physicist will pronounce according to the meaning "not ionized", while the plumber will treat it as "formed a union".

Comment: Well answered Sir!

Comment: Unfortunately for us, our physicist just got back from a debate about employment law and the plumber is self-employed and reads about particle physics for fun. </snark>

Comment: Blech.  I've heard this line from a relative who thinks it's absolutely hilarious.  I have even made a special point of trying it on people from various walks of life and all professions.  Long story short: they _all_ do as the plumber, because that way is simply more common.  She still thinks it's funny anyway.  Bleeeeecchhhhhh.

Comment: And here I was hoping for a super mario reference :-(

Comment: @imallett I would pronounce it like the physicist, not like the plumber (and I'm not even a physicist).

Comment: Wouldn't the physicist prefer the term de-ionised?

Answer (score 11):

> σ. The physicist will say "sigma", the plumber will say "huh?", assuming a non-greek plumber.

Comment: And if a third person is heard to use the phrase "assuming a non-greek plumber", then this must be a mathematician :)

Answer (score 7):

> TeV
>
>  The plumber will almost certainly pronounce it as the Latvian dative second person singular pronoun, whereas the particle physicist will read it as tera-electron-volt.

Answer (score 4):

> Unionised:
>  Plumber will pronounce it as the boolean operation and the physicist as not an ion but an atom

Answer (score 3):

Per my father, who is both:

> Auger - which to the physicist would be pronounced in [French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Victor_Auger) and to the plumber would be pronounced in [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auger_(drill)).

Answer (score 1):

> de Broglie

because

> It is the name of a famous physicist, one of the fathers of quantum mechanics.
>   Any physicist would have heard of him during their studies.
>
>   His name is pronounced something like "de Broy".  A physicist would know that.
>   Anybody not familiar with quantum mechanics would make it rhyme with "ugly".
>
>   (OK, it is 2 words.  DeBroglie or simply Broglie would also do.)

Comment: sadly I have studied about wave particle duality and my teacher(me too) pronounced it in a way which rhymed with ugly.

Comment: That better works for french-speaking physicists, I guess.

Comment: I can't say I'm neither French nor European.